# Calculate the volume of the region using triple integration.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A region bounded by the planes $x=0 , y=0 ,z=0 ,x+y=4, x=z-y-1$

I want to calculate the volume of the region using triple integration.

so what bounds should i use for the triple integration.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried sketching the region in ${\mathbb{R}^3}$?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose yeah i did the sketch, the problem was that the region is to be taken only on the octant where x , y, z all are +ve. But the plane x=z-y-1 also covered the region outside the 1st octant, i.e region between 0 and 1 in z axis . So my question was with the bound which i was choosing, will it take the region outside 1st octant or not.

Comment: Please add your thoughts in the post, not in comments.

Comment: @StubbornAtom i used to, but then they will say , question is unclear.  Hence i just went directly and asked as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just start by any one dimension although some are easier to calculate.

The integration starting by $z$ looks like $$\int_{0}^{4} \int_{0}^{4 - x} \int_{0}^{x + y + 1} \,dz \,dy \,dx.$$ Is this what you need? Or do your teacher asks you to start it by $x$?

Comment: Yeah thanks!, and i don't have any teacher.